# In Salesforce, what is the easiest way to programmatically change a Contact Owner AND notify that User (via email) of the change?

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

When manually changing Contact Owners in Salesforce, there is a checkbox that says "Send Notification Email."  Is there a way to programmatically check that box when updating contacts using APEX?

Answer (score 0):

You need [`DMLOptions`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_database_dmloptions.htm) class and [`Database.update(records, options)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_database.htm) version of the call, not the usual `update records;`. Something like

```
Database.DmlOptions options = new Database.DmlOptions();
options.emailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;
List<Contact> contacts [SELECT Id FROM Contact LIMIT 10];
Database.update(contacts, options);
```

But it means failed update (validation rule, required field etc) will not throw an exception anymore. It's your job to examine what the `Database.update` returned and decide if you have to rollback the transaction or maybe you're fine with "save what you can, swallow all errors"...

It's work ;) I don't like work. You really need apex code for this? Maybe a workflow, flow or process builder on `ISCHANGED(OwnerId)` + email alert would suffice?